# Как организовать парсинг раскрывающего списка из json файла?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Стоит задача организовать список категорий, в каждой категории есть субкатегория.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $.getJSON("categories.json", function (data){
    var myCategories = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val ){

        myCategories.push('<li class="col-md-4 lw" id="' + key + '">' + val.title  +
                '<img src ="'+ val.ico +'"/>' +  '</li>');
        if (key === 'children') {
            var mySubCategories = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < mySubCategories.length; i++){
                myCategories.push('<li class="ss" id="' + key + '">' + val.title  +  '</li>');
            };
            $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-sub-list',
                html: mySubCategories.join('')
            }).appendTo(".lw");
        };
    });
    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: myCategories.join('')
    }).appendTo(".container");
})
```

Как выводить дочерние списки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так: http://jsfiddle.net/r1qkL8tr/

```
var list = '';

function parseCatRecursive(item){
    for(var key in item){
        if(key !== 'children') list += '<li id="' + key + '">' + item[key] + '</li>';
        if(key === 'children' && item[key].length !== 0) {
            list += '<li>Подкатегория<ul>';
            parseCatRecursive(item[key]); 
            list += '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
}

categories.forEach(function(item){
    list += '<ul>';
    parseCatRecursive(item);
    list += '</ul>';
});

$('body').html(list);
```

**Обновление**

Я не знаю что Вам нужно выводить, дочерние списки выводятся, вот новый пример: http://jsfiddle.net/r1qkL8tr/1/

Вот с полем *title*: http://jsfiddle.net/r1qkL8tr/2/

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку. Но тут выводится все списком даже id

Comment: Получается вот так http://jsfiddle.net/Radik_Zu/racn89j1/